# open specific website at startup

Tags: 12.04, websites

In windows it is possible to add a policy so that a specific website will open every time a user logs in. Is this possible in Ubuntu also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open Startup Applications from dash. Click on Add.

[image]

Give the Name of your choice. In command box type `firefox www.ubuntu.com` and click Add.
Replace firefox by your preferred browser and ubuntu.com by your preferred website.

Comment: @iankuper please mark the answer as accepted by ckicking tick mark on the right to close the topic.